# SaveMany and DeteleAll using CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How does **saveMany** (to save multiple records in one query) as well as **deleteAll** (to delete multiple rows from database at once using row id or any other field) work (controller perspective) using CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation it is *all* there

- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#saving-associations
- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#cascading-deletes
- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#converting-request-data-into-entities

including examples.

Comment: True, though saving multiple entities (in a transaction) is somewhat hidden in the [**how to convert request data**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#converting-request-data-into-entities) section.

Comment: I've added it. I don't think it is a problem, at least not for people who care to read the documentation.